# How can I solve this system of 6 simple quadratic diophantine equations in four variables?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations, findinstance

I generated [this text file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/main/pythagorean_stu_Arty_.txt) containing tuples $(\sqrt{s}, \sqrt{t}, \sqrt{u}, s,t,u,t+u,t+u-s,t-s)$ where the six variables $s,t,u,t+u,t+u-s,t-s$ are all squares. An excerpt of the data set is:

```
153, 185, 672, 23409, 34225, 451584, 485809, 462400, 10816
264, 520, 975, 69696, 270400, 950625, 1221025, 1151329, 200704
264, 561, 952, 69696, 314721, 906304, 1221025, 1151329, 245025
306, 370, 1344, 93636, 136900, 1806336, 1943236, 1849600, 43264
357, 1325, 6960, 127449, 1755625, 48441600, 50197225, 50069776, 1628176
448, 952, 495, 200704, 906304, 245025, 1151329, 950625, 705600
459, 555, 2016, 210681, 308025, 4064256, 4372281, 4161600, 97344
```

My task is to iterate each line/row of this file and to try finding a solution $0<w<x<y<z$ of the following system of six diophantine equation:

- $x^2-w^2=s\qquad z^2-w^2=t+u$
- $y^2-w^2=t\qquad z^2-x^2=t+u-s$
- $z^2-y^2=u\qquad y^2-x^2=t-s$

What I tried so far is running the following script with more relaxed conditions:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
arr = Import[
   "C:/Users/esultano/git/pythagorean/pythagorean_stu_Arty_.txt", 
   "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 0];
f[i_] := Part[arr[[i]], 1 ;; 3];
len = Length[arr];
For[i = 1, i < len, i++, {
  triplet = f[i];
  s = triplet[[1]];
  t = triplet[[2]];
  u = triplet[[3]];
  (*Print[FactorInteger[s]];*)
  ins = FindInstance[
    x*x - w*w == s*s && y*y - w*w == t*t && w != 0, {w, x, y}, 
    Integers];
  If[Length[ins] > 
    0, {ins = 
     Join[First[ins], {"z" -> N[Sqrt[u^2 + First[ins][[3, 2]]^2], 20],
        "s" -> s, "t" -> t, "u" -> u}]; Print[ins]}, Continue];
  ins = FindInstance[
    y*y - w*w == t*t && z*z - y*y == u*u && w != 0, {w, y, z}, 
    Integers];
  If[Length[ins] > 
    0, {ins = 
     Join[First[ins], {"x" -> N[Sqrt[s^2 + First[ins][[1, 2]]^2], 20],
        "s" -> s, "t" -> t, "u" -> u}]; Print[ins]}, Continue];
  }
 ]
```

It gives me "almost" solutions, for example $(w,x,y,z)=(40579,58565,65221,196605.2940)$. It seems not to be possible to combine the conditions such for example:

```
ins = FindInstance[x*x-w*w==s*s && y*y-w*w==t*t && z*z-y*y==u*u && w > 0, {w, x, y, z}, Integers]
```

Is there a way to let Mathematica solve such a system of diophantine equations?

The background is a quite inteersting problem, namely a search for four squares as described [here at this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342283/for-integers-xyz-why-are-these-cases-impossible-for-mengolis-six-square-pr) - an extended version of Mengoli's Six Square Problem. It would be great if Mathematica can solve the above shown system of these six diophantine equations.

Comment: Mathematically interesting problem of finding 4-tuples. UpVoting this question, as it will be useful for the whole world of Math.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading things - but are you expecting integer solutions? You call the example above an "almost" solution. Do you believe it should be finding an integer solution?

Comment: Yes - you are totally correct. I need integer solutions - in my current code I have "almost" solutions, since one value (here `z`) is not an integer. I strongly believe that for higher values there might occur a solution - hopefully. Even if we find nothing - this would be a result (good to know) as well.

Comment: Yes, it often happens that bigger values may give some solution. For example after many distributed (on cluster) CPU-years of computation just recently mathematicians found solution `42 = (-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3`, i.e. represented 42 as sum of cubes. To remind, 42 was the Ultimate Answer to Meaning of Life according to [Hitchhiker's Guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy). It is a good example when in small numbers solution doesn't exist but start existing from 20 or 30 digit numbers size.

Comment: BTW, regarding my comment above - informal description of 42 as cubes finding [is here](https://news.mit.edu/2021/solution-3-sum-cubes-puzzle-0311) which also includes 3 as sum of cubes which is `569936821221962380720^3 + (−569936821113563493509)^3 + (−472715493453327032)^3 = 3`. Probably their distributed search was registering all found answers below 1000.

Comment: Would be more accommodating if rather than post a link to the data you simply  posted some examples of the data such as the first 10 lines of the file.

Comment: Sorry - you are totally right. I added an excerpt.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Now that you have an accepted answer, have you found any solutions for your large data set?  If so, I would appreciate seeing a few here.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: First of all: Thank you for your comprehensive and useful answer. I ran it yesterday (overnight) and unfortunatelly it did not found a solution. Maybe we have to extend the search space (larger numbers). I committed the Notebook [here at GitHUb](https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/mathematica/pythagorean_mse.nb). It shows `{51901.3,{}}` and `{865.021,{}}`.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Will and values of `{s. t. u}` that are squares of integers due, or are the values special in some other way?

Comment: @bbgodfrey: We collected all these `[s,t,u]` values by bruteforce iteratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

arr = Cases[
   Import[
    "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/data.txt", "CSV"],
   {_Integer ..}, 1];

Length@arr

(* 27060 *)
```

Verifying that every line of `arr` matches the template `{Sqrt[s], Sqrt[t], Sqrt[u], s, t, u, t+u, t+u-s, t-s}`

```
And @@ ((repl = Thread[{s, t, u} -> #[[4 ;; 6]]];
     # == ({Sqrt[s], Sqrt[t], Sqrt[u], s, t, u, t + u, t + u - s, t - s} /.
              repl)) & /@ arr)

(* True *)
```

Since there are more equations than variables, the [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) must be used.

```
sol[s_Integer?Positive, t_Integer?Positive, u_Integer?Positive] :=
 Solve[{
   x^2 - w^2 == s, z^2 - w^2 == t + u, y^2 - w^2 == t,
   z^2 - x^2 == t + u - s, z^2 - y^2 == u, y^2 - x^2 == t - s,
   0 < w < x < y < z}, {w, x, y, z}, Integers,
  MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

There are no solutions for the first 20 lines of `arr`

```
at = AbsoluteTiming[
  arr2 = Select[arr[[1 ;; 20]], Length[sol @@ #[[4 ;; 6]]] > 0 &]]

(* {2.05478, {}} *)
```

It would take about 50 minutes to run through the data (assuming that nothing else is competing for processing time).

```
Length[arr]*(at/20)/60

(* 46.3353 *)
```

Comment: BTW, does Mathematica Guarantee that for each (s, t, u) line in data file it finds exactly ALL possible solutions for system? In other words does it search symbolically all Infinite space of possible (w, x, y, z)? Or it finds them until some limit, for example `2^64` at most?

Comment: In general `Solve` can miss solutions for some problems. If you want more rigor, use `Reduce`

Comment: Have you obtained a few solutions that you could share?

Comment: @bbgodfrey - As shown, I only tested the first 20 lines and found no solutions.

Comment: My code above has a relaxed condition and it found some "almost" solutions, for example `[w=67375, x=-89425, y=−114695, z=196769.2970]`. See here the [MSE Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286376/four-squares-such-that-the-difference-of-any-two-is-a-square/4364401#4364401) that describes the mathematical motivation and provides some "almost" solutions.